# Upgrading PHP on MacOS Sierra

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to update my php to the current version on my MacOS Sierra.

1. When I type in vi ~/.bash-profile, all I get is a series of "~". How exactly do I update the PATH?
2. sudo vi /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini gives me a ton of text, and when I try to run the next command (sudo cat /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/local.ini >> /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini) I get permission denied. How do I go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. If you are not familiar with the `vi` editor, you probably want to use another text editor. On OS X for example (this should open TextEdit normally...):
   `$ open ~/.bash_profile`
   If that does not give you TextEdit, you
   can also do:
   `$ open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`
2. If your user doesn't have sudo permissions, you need to login as root or as a user who does have super user privileges. That would be the only way you can change that file.

Comment: I'll try using Atom, that works too right? And I am indeed logged in as root, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @SanchitBatra If you are logged-in as root, you don't need `sudo`.

Comment: @SanchitBatra So you should start with adding the `export` line I guess :-) By the way, it is just a simple text file so the editor you use does not really matter as long as you know it.

Comment: Okay thank you! I felt weird adding what I assumed to be a terminal command inside a text file for some reason.

Comment: So I added the export line, but the second set of commands is giving me this:

Comment: -bash: /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini: Permission denied